# The grouby in pandas is giving wrong sum for grouping by date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to sum the volume by date. The data consists of daily volumes produced by 3 different entities. I want the sum of the volumes of all 3 entities on each day . There is no column for entity. Just Date and volume such that each date might repeat 3 times.

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
            Date          Volume (Pounds)
        0   2012-01-02  658,656
        1   2012-01-03  748,242
        2   2012-01-04  494,298
        3   2012-01-05  467,352
        4   2012-01-06  678,249
        5   2012-01-07  372,492
```

I used the groupby function in pandas but, the outcome (sum on each day) was way higher than expected.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df_new = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')]).sum()
```

The new df looks like this: (has unresonably high values)

```
    Date           Volume (Pounds)
    2012-01-02  658,65623,400
    2012-01-03  748,24226,064
    2012-01-04  494,29832,382
    2012-01-05  467,35269,804
    2012-01-06  678,24918,000
    2012-01-07  372,4924,779
```

I expect the sums to be no more than 8 or 9 digits.

Comment: Is `Volume` really a numeric Series? It seems to be a string and you are concatenating strings.

Comment: df['Volume (Pounds)']=pd.to_numeric(df['Volume (Pounds)'].str.replace(',','')), then run your code

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't notice that!